# javascript function work on localhost but doesn't work on iis

Tags: javascript, php, html, iis

I did a little web page. This page has Dropdow linked to the database of dependencies that normally run on localhost. But when I try to access through the domain name with the IIS server stops working. Are always in "Load" mode.

Can someone tell me why this happens?

It will be me who can help please?

Thank you all.
Any questions I try to explain better.

sincere Greetings

**Code of Html dependent Dropdown**

```
<tr><td for="category"><font color=white>Local:</font></td><td>
    <select name="parent_cat5" id="parent_cat5" style="width:60px;">
        <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_parent4)): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['idBuilding']; ?>"><?php echo $row['idBuilding']; ?></option>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </select> <select name="idLocal" id="idLocal" style="width:176px;" title="Select the Local" required></select>
```

**Code of javascript dependent Dropdown**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#parent_cat5").change(function() {
        $(this).after('<div id="loader"><img src="img/loading.gif" alt="loading subcategory" /></div>');
        $.get('loadsubcat.php?parent_cat5=' + $(this).val(), function(data) {
            $("#idLocal").html(data);
            $('#loader').slideUp(200, function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }); 
    });

});
</script>
```

Localhost

[image]

IIS

[image]

The strange thing is that works 100% through localhost and doesn't work through IIS.

I had a jQuery Datepicker and works fine...

Comment: Make sure your `loadsubcat.php` script returns valid response

Comment: Definitely what haim770 said, do a console log of `data` in your get function and check whether your response structure is valid and what you expect it to be

Comment: Thanks for reply. I think that loadsubcat.php script returns valid response, because it works correctly through localhost.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, yes, jquery is present...

Comment: I had a jQuery Datepicker and works fine...

Comment: You can try to add a `.fail()` to your `$.get()` to see if your AJAX request is actually working :)

Comment: @Eclecticist like this: $.get('loadsubcat.php?parent_cat5=' + $(this).val(), function(data).fail(){  ??

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

Go to IIS->Application Poll->Managed Pipeline Mode->Change from Classic Mode for Integrated Mode and all works fine!